# How to discards the drafts and update in real-time in google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have google app scripts and it gets the current message drafts and its deletes it. But unless, I refresh the page, that discard message is still there. Is it possible to discard the drafts and update immediately without refreshing the gmail page.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can not tell apps-script to refresh the window for you, there is not such a functionality.

How much is the delay you're experiencing to actually get the draft discarded on your browser? I mean, it really should not take much time to gmail service workers to update those windows.

The only workaround I can imagine is to build a browser extension to auto-update the gmail tabs and execute the scripts.